# Download a search result from Twitter using webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python and newer to webscraping, so my question might be very basic.

I am trying to use webscraping to download some results from Twitter searches. I have already understood how the urls of searches work, so I am directly accessing the urls of the searches.

I expect most of my searches to provide no results, and I would like to extract that information in those cases. I’m going to use an example of a search which returns no results. The url would be:
https://twitter.com/search?q=%22John%20Doe%22%20stackexchange%20trial&src=typed_query

That would return something like:

[image]

I am trying to extract the text ‘No results for ""John Doe" stackexchange trial"’. But there is something in my code which is not working.

The html code from that part is:

[image]

The code I am trying is the following:

```
import os  
os.getcwd()  
os.chdir('my.dir') 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import pandas as pd
import os
import urllib.request
import requests
import re

urlpage = "https://twitter.com/search?q=%22John%20Doe%22%20stackexchange%20trial&src=typed_query"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find("main", class_="css-1dbjc4n r-16y2uox r-1wbh5a2") 
text_element = results.find("span", class_="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0")
text = text_element.text
print(text)
```

I believe the problem is when I define "results", it is not finding what I want.

I got to that version of the code by analogy from a code which does actually work, which is the following:

```
urlpage="https://stackexchange.com/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(urlpage)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(id='content') 
print(results.prettify())
title = results.find('h3', class_='title')
print(title.text)
```

Thank you very much in advance for all your help!

**Edit:** so apparently BeautifulSoup doesn’t work for this (I’m not sure why, I think it has to do with the way Twitter loads its elements). I had to use Selenium.

Here is a code that does the job:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import time

url = r'https://twitter.com/search?q=%22John%20Doe%22%20stackexchange%20trial&src=typed_query'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'No results')]")
print(element.text)
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to web scrape and not use the API? Is it because you had issues getting API access?

Comment: Hello. As I understand it, the free API gives search results from tweets posted within the last 7 days. I need the results which include all tweets. The premium API would work I think, but I cannot spend money on that.